# Freezing First Columns and Fist Column's Headers, cross browser solution?

Tags: asp.net

I Have Page That Have GridView This GridView Have a Lot Of Rows my clients Want To Freeze The Fisrt column and curresponding header, and I tried below code

CSS

```
div#div-datagrid 
{
/*style="height: 382px; overflow: scroll; width: 100%"*/
width:  100%;
height: 382px;
overflow: scroll;
/*scrollbar-base-color:#ffeaff;*/
}

/* Locks the left column */
td.locked, th.locked {
position:relative;
cursor: default;
background-color: White;
/*IE5+ only*/
left:expression(document.getElementById("div-datagrid").scrollLeft-2);
}
```

.CS

```
protected void myGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
e.Row.Cells[0].CssClass = "locked";
e.Row.Cells[1].CssClass = "locked";
}
```

This is working fine in IE but not working in FF and Chrome. Any Solution?

Comment: Why not have the first two columns 'faked' in a separate table? Just make sure the widths and heights match then have the actual gridview to the right of them. Style it so the left column looks like it's part of the gridview. Would probably work better across all browsers.

Comment: I can't split the grid,do u have any other solution?